# PHP dependencies on composer. In fact I modified the source code of a dependency and there is no impact

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with my PHP dependencies on composer. In fact I modified the source code of a dependency and there is no impact. I work with laravel 6, and I would like to modify the dependency Craftable more particularly to modify the default language by mine.

How could I apply my changes?

Comment: If you want a specific modification on a package, you can create a fork, creating your own package. The next step is: Is your modification useful to others? If yes, try a pull request to original package.